# Is it possible to transform a POJO object to DocumentSnapshot in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read the docs and something like it is possible:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                City city = document.toObject(City.class); //Possible
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is it somehow possible to transform later that `city` object back to a DocumentSnapshot object? I need that, because my City class is Serializable while `DocumentSnapshot` is not.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a DocumentSnapshot later?

Comment: @DougStevenson I need to pass it to `query.startAfter(lastVisibleDocumentSnapshot);`. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you will need the original DocumentSnapshot, or pass the ID of the document to start from.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks again, Doug. It's nowhere written that we can pass the ID of the document to the `startAfter` instead of a DocumentSnapshot object. That's solved my entire problem, waw! You are really great.

Comment: Not every method is described in the formal documentation.  The API documentation lists everything - you should review it to understand all your options.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#startAfter(java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to pass it to `query.startAfter(lastVisibleDocumentSnapshot);`. You will need the original DocumentSnapshot, or pass the ID of the Document to start from.

Not every method is described in the formal documentation. The [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#startAfter(java.lang.Object...)) lists everything - It is well worth to review it to understand all your options.